# PostgreSQL Can't connect to remote server running under root

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers

I have a postgresql server up and running under root. It's in a docker container and the exposed port is 5434. My API docker container is able to connect to this server, but I can't access it from my local machine, the connection is getting timed out.

Here's the output of the command `ps -elf|grep root`

```
4 S root     15264  5623  0  80   0 -  2128 -      Jan25 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 5434 -container-ip 172.18.0.5 -container-port 5432
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that Postgres is running in a Docker container, your IP is not local anymore, so you need to update the [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for the server to allow connections from the network from which you are accessing Postgres.